# ionic realtime database updates

Tags: angularjs, ionic-framework

I'm developing a coffee ordering app using ionic and angularJS and I'm using a mysql database with a laravel backend. 
Now i want to check whether a certain order has completed or not in real time. Instead of sending $http requests every second to check with the server is there a way to update the app only when the mysql database gets changed in ionic?
I was told pusher.js does the trick but I have no idea how to integrate it with ionic.

Thank you in advanvce

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using socket should be a best solution for real time updates without repetitive requests from front-end. You can use http://socket.io/ on front-end and on PHP backend as mentioned  at http://php.net/manual/en/function.socket-create.php.

Comment: socket would be the way to go